# How many balls do we need to draw from the urn?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have a urn with 24 red balls and 8 blue balls. We randomly draw n balls from the urn with replacement of the balls. How big must n be such that the probability of drawing at least 2 red balls is 0.9?

If $n=0$ or $n=1$, it is impossible to draw $2$ red balls.

If $n=2$, we need to draw $2$ red balls and the chance of that is $\frac{24}{32} \cdot \frac{24}{32}= 0.5625$

If $n=3$ we could either draw $2$ out of $3$ red balls or $3$ out of $3$. So the chance is
$\left(\frac{24}{32}\right)^3 \cdot \frac{8}{32} + \left(\frac{24}{32}\right)^4 = 0.421875$

This is smaller than the number above. This can't be! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you get $\left(\frac{24}{32}\right)^3\times \frac{8}{32} + \left(\frac{24}{32}\right)^4$?

Answer (score 1):

If $n=3$ we could either draw $2$ out of $3$ red balls or $3$ out of $3$. So the chance is
${3 \choose 2}\left(\frac{24}{32}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{8}{32} + {3 \choose 3}\left(\frac{24}{32}\right)^3 \approx 0.84$ which is bigger than the number above.

Comment: Thank you. Why do we have the binomial coefficients ${3 \choose 2}$ and ${3 \choose 3}$ there? What does that mean?

Comment: Choosing the positions for the reds.  With 2 reds and 1 black, you can have RRB, RBR or BRR, i.e. ${3 \choose 2}=3$ different possibilities

Comment: Thank you very much, Henry!